# Setting and using parameters from parent class

Tags: php, class

Is there any way I can write my code something like this:

```
<?php

class BaseClass {   
    public $testvar;

    public function __construct ($testvar) {
        $this->testvar = $testvar;
    }
}

class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
}

class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass {
}

$bc = new BaseClass('test1');
$cc1 = new ChildClass1();
$bc->testvar = 'test2';
$cc2 = new ChildClass2();

echo $cc1->testvar; // should echo 'test1'
echo $cc2->testvar; // should echo 'test2'
?>
```

The reason I am asking is so that I don't have to specify the parameters every time I create a new child class. I want to make it so I only have to specify the parameters once (preferably when creating the base class).

Is this possible?

Comment: Every instance of the class is completely separated from each other! This is not how OOP works.

Answer (score 0):

It's the point of object oriented programming that every instance has it's own parameters.

But sometimes you just want to use a class once for the whole application. Like a database controller or a router. You can then use static properties and methods:

```
class BaseClass {
    public static $testvar;

    public function __construct ($testvar) {
        self::$testvar = $testvar;
    }
}
```

Note that the value of the static `$testvar` is the same in all objects. You could work around that with something like this:"

```
class BaseClass {
    public $testvar;
    public static $test_var;

    public function __construct ($testvar = '') {
        if (!empty($testvar)) {
            self::$test_var = $testvar;
        }

        $this->testvar = self::$test_var;
    }
}

class ChildClass1 extends BaseClass {
}

class ChildClass2 extends BaseClass {
}

$bc = new BaseClass('test1');
$cc1 = new ChildClass1();
echo $cc1->testvar; // should echo 'test1'

BaseClass::$test_var = 'test2';
$cc2 = new ChildClass2();

echo $cc1->testvar; // **should echo 'test1'**
echo $cc2->testvar; // should echo 'test2'
```

Comment: Your second example does not work like expected, because you cannot declare a static and an instance variable with the same name. You will get an "Fatal Error". The second problem is, that you have to declare the $testvar parameter in the constructor as optional to resolve the warnings.

Comment: It was just an example of how he could get what he wants using static and dynamic properties. But you're right, I edited my answer.